# How to use the import package with folders containing accented (non-English) letters in their names?

Tags: texlive, accents, mac, import, folders

To illustrate my problem, suppose that you have the master file `main.tex` and a chapter called `chapter.tex` in a subfolder called `folder`. Both files use UTF8 encoding. Then, the following minimal code example compiles fine:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\includefrom{folder/}{chapter}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% chapter.tex
\lipsum[1]
```

How should I change the code above if the subfolder contains accents in its name (e.g. `fólder` instead of `folder`)? Changing the `\includefrom` to

```
\includefrom{fólder/}{chapter}
```

or

```
\includefrom{f\'older/}{chapter}
```

wouldn't help.

Thanks,
Ádám

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me with `\includefrom{fólder/}{chapter}` as is. What is the error you get?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I uploaded the wrong MWE (I've been trying for a while and had a couple of similar files circulating). Now I uploaded the one that gives me the `No file chapter.tex.` result.

Comment: It works this way, as well. Sorry for asking, but in which folder you have `chapter.tex` now?

Comment: `chapter.tex` is inside the folder called `fólder`. To stay on the safe side, I copied the files again from this page and created brand new files to test the results. Can this be an OS or TeX-version specific issue? I'm using TeX Live 2012 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Again, sorry for asking, but `main.tex` now has the line `\includefrom{fólder/}{chapter}`?

Comment: Yes. I tried both using `\includefrom{folder/}{chapter}` and `\includefrom{fólder/}{chapter}`. Neither do work for me.

Comment: Well, I don't know why it happens. I use MiKTeX on Windows and it works fine. Perhaps is it due to the OS?

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work with OS X. This is because the default format for the filesystem is to be not case-sensitive (so e.g. there would be no difference between `CHAPTER.tex` and `chapter.tex`). So I'm afraid you can't do this in OS X.  See [Is bash in OSX case-insensitive?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22297) for some details.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. However, I don't see how case sensitivity is connected to non-English accents in a path. I can create two subfolders within the same folder with the names differing only in accents (e.g. `folder` and `fóldér`). The OS will recognize these as two different folders. Is there a way to force TeX (more precisely, the `import` package when loaded together with `inputenc` and `fontenc`) to recognize them as well?

Comment: You're right.  Your minimal document works with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Unfortunately, this is a document that I have to hand in to a publisher using LaTeX (I'm simply not in the position of arguing with them about this). On the other hand, my specification says that the chapters should be put in subfolders with the same name as that of the chapters. Apparently, some chapter names contain accents. It is nice to know that at least on MiKTeX this works fine, however, I'd be happy to see a solution that I could use on my own computer as well, while working on this book...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the non ASCII characters are expanded. Inhibit their expansion with `\detokenize`; this should work on any operating system.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\includefrom{\detokenize{fólder/}}{chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! In fact, I was assuming exactly the same, however, I didn't know about the `\detokenize` macro and Google didn't find it for me. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you removed `inputenc` it would work with xelatex as that is naturally utf-8. with inputenc utf-8 characters are made active and given macro definitions that *typeset* appropriate characters, however those typesetting instructions don't work for a filename, however this works

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\includefrom{f\stringólder/}{chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Strangely, this doesn't work here. I am getting an 'Undefined control sequence' error in `\@sub@import ...egingroup \protected@edef \@tempa {\endgroup \let \noexpand ...`, triggered from the line `\includefrom{f\stringÃ³lder/}{chapter}`.

Comment: @SiskaÁdám It worked for me with TL2013. Slightly odd that egreg's version worked if this didn't as they are both similar internally, however glad you got something working:-)