# Is there any reason to use inputenc?

Tags: input-encodings

My LaTeX text editor is GNU Emacs 25.1.1, which encodes text files in UTF-8. Is there any reason to specify

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in the preamble? Even if I migrate to a different computer with a different TeX installation, is there any risk that the migrated LaTeX files will be misinterpreted if I leave out this line?

Comment: It is at least mandatory if you use any utf8 characters that are non-ASCII (like the German Umlaute "äöü").

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But if a TeX engine can process my files at all it means that it is UTF-8-aware, so it realizes that my files are encoded as UTF-8, so what purpose does the `inputenc` line serve?

Comment: @EvanAad try inserting something like `ä` or `ß`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But must not all utf-8 files begin with the triple of bytes 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF? So if a TeX engine expects pure ASCII and it encounters these three bytes as the first three bytes, why won't it reject the file? Since if it was a valid TeX file, it should begin with whitespace followed by `\documentclass` no?

Comment: Related: [fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc), [What is the difference between font encoding and input encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/what-is-the-difference-between-font-encoding-and-input-encoding) and [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark)

Comment: @EvanAad Your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: @egreg: How so?

Comment: @EvanAad A UTF-8 encoded file does need `inputenc` if run with `pdflatex`; in this case the BOM might give errors. You don't need `inputenc` for files run with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, provided you load `fontspec`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But my conclusion is a logical consequence of the answers, so if it is wrong, the answers are wrong too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is exactly the situation reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10474/21685) and according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10478/21685), until `inputenc` has been encountered, only ASCII should be used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I disagree. If there is a BOM and the TeX engine expects ASCII, the .tex file will fail to process and an error will be reported. This will be the case whether or not an `inputenc` line is included. Therefore, the `inputenc` line is not necessary.

Comment: It isn't strictly true (but not the subject of this question) to say the engine expects ascii it will accept the full byte range the format may or may not be programmed to accept characters at that point. But in any case saying that inputenc is not needed if there is a BOM is entirely misleading for future readers of the site it implies that the BOM is somehow telling latex that the file is utf8 which simply is not the case. if it works with the BOM and no inputenc it would work without  BOM and no inputenc and the entire mention of UT-8 is a red herring. You should delete the conclusion.

Comment: It is theoretically possible that some future TeX engine could recognize the BOM and use it to autodetect the input character set and set up the equivalent of `inputenc`. However, actually-existing implementations do not do so. A BOM will either be ignored, or it will be an error.

Comment: Related question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex/)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Update as of April 2018:**

The community has changed its default encoding to UTF-8 as of April 2018 (see https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121ltnews28.pdf). So, the remark regarding LuaTeX or XeTeX applies to all compilers by now:

> `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be omitted, since it does basically nothing

**Original answer:**

The basic LaTeX/TeX engine expects (or perhaps is meant to process) pure `ASCII` input. Whenever your file  uses any other characters, the `inputenc` package comes to the rescue, specifying to the engine how to process the symbols you're typing.

So it's quite necessary, whenever you use unicode (non `ASCII`) characters, to use the `inputenc` package, in order to have a meaningful output (or sometimes to make a successful run of (La)TeX)

The difference comes with the "naturally UTF8 compliant" engines, such as LuaTeX and XeTeX, which automatically interpret the input files as `UTF8` and won't accept different input encodings: in that cases `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be omitted, since it does basically nothing (and is not used internally anyway)

To put it in other terms, the programs do not check whether the file characters comply to the ASCII standards, they simply interpret them to be as such.

Comment: If I feed a UTF-8-encoded .tex file to a TeX engine that expects pure ASCII, won't it just fail with an error message?

Comment: @EvanAad no try the example in my answer you get no error you just get different characters (same as on a web page if you serve an html  file with the wrong encoding)

Comment: But must not all utf-8 files begin with the triple of bytes 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF? So if a TeX engine expects pure ASCII and it encounters these three bytes as the first three bytes, why won't it reject the file, since if it were a valid TeX file, it should begin with whitespace followed by \documentclass no?

Comment: @EvanAad No, the Byte Order Mark is not mandatory at all (and would actually confuse LaTeX).

Comment: @EvanAad for example wikipedia's utf-8 page says The Unicode Standard neither requires nor recommends the use of the BOM for UTF-8, but does allow the character to be at the start of a file.[34] The presence of the UTF-8 BOM may cause problems with existing software that could otherwise handle UTF-8, for example:

Comment: @EvanAad: No, BOM is strongly discouraged in UTF-8 and is utterly invalid in many contexts (like some programming/script language source files) that might be UTF-8. Basically only some misguided windows-based editors insert BOM in UTF-8 without you manually entering/asking-for it.

Comment: @R.. There is one context in which I would encourage a BOM: there is *no* other way to get Visual Studio 2012 to read a source file encoded in UTF-8, and no other encoding that just works in MSVC, gcc and clang. (There is now a command-line option to select UTF-8 in MSVC and gcc.) And compilers old enough to choke on the BOM probably don’t understand UTF-8 in string literals either. Better they fail noisily than silently. So maybe it’s a workaround for a Microsoft problem that they have since fixed, but that’s the most portable encoding for C/C++ source right now.

Comment: Well, other than ASCII with `\u` and `\U` escapes, of course.

Comment: @Davislor: A C source file beginning with a BOM is syntactically invalid. See the language grammar. For better or worse, it's still difficult to use UTF-8 in C sources. As part of (non-wide) string literals it's always worked (practically if not formally, because historically they're just treated as bytes) but otherwise it's not supported by the language without `\u`/`\U` or compiler extensions.

Comment: @R.. The C11 standard does not forbid the BOM.  It says, “The source character set may contain multibyte characters” and that “The  presence, meaning, and representation of any additional members [besides ASCII characters] is locale-specific.”  It also explicitly allows extended characters inside comments and string literals. All major compilers support the UTF-8 BOM, and the standard permits them to do so. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf (5.2.1.2)

Comment: @Davislor: I disagree with your interpretation of that text, but the overall point is not C-specific (and not worth getting into a C language-lawyering argument), just that BOM is not safe in general. For instance it's certainly invalid/unsafe in scripts with an interpreter denoted by `#!` notation at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @R.. You’re right that this isn’t the right place for C language-lawyering. I note that *every* major compiler implementation agrees with me that it is legal to classify a BOM as whitespace in the source character set, and changing that would break a huge amount of existing source code for no benefit.

Comment: @R.. I also agree that BOM is not a good idea for UTF-8 files *in most cases*. However, certain versions of Visual Studio require it, so code that needs to be portable to them are an exception.

Answer (score 40):

With the 2018 release of LaTeX the test file below produces

[image]

as UTF-8 is assumed as the default input encoding unless you specify a different encoding to `inputenc` and the BOM at the start of the file is handled gracefully (ignored in this case).

---

**Original answer**

With inputenc commented out I get

[image]

despite typing the input in emacs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

© David Carlisle and cost £2000.
\end{document}
```

Since there seem to be some discussion about the BOM..

If the above file is saved with the byte order mark (or any printable character) before the `\documentclass` then you get an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

but this is not built in to the TeX engine, it is just the default setting of the characters which can be changed depending how you call LaTeX

The commandline

```
pdflatex '\catcode"EF=9\catcode"BB=9\catcode"BF=9 \input' testfile
```

would declare the BOM safe and latex would then process the file without error and give the same bad output as shown above. The presence of the BOM in no way implies UTF-8 encoding to the system.

Comment: Just like you changed the catcode for the UTF-8 BOM, you can change the catcode for the backslash character, and then the file won't compile even if it contains the `\inputenc` line.

Comment: @EvanAad the interpretation of every _byte_ is setable within tex or even as I show here in the call to a particular file, your assertion that the engine is restricted to ascii is false even by default and the assertion that a leading byte order mark necessarily gives an error due to the engine's ascii nature is also false. It is just a feature of the tex assignments (which could be in the format or on the commandline) many editors do assignments like this  on the commandline routinely when they run tex in the background.

Comment: @EvanAad making `\ ` not be the escape character would just be peverse but a commandline such as I show above would be a perfectly reasonable way to set up emacs tex command if you had to share files with someone using an editor that insisted on adding a BOM. You can make it safe, but it does nothing.

Comment: FWIW, the combination of BOM / UTF-8 is discouraged anyway. A BOM only makes sense with UTF-16 / UTF-32 encodings, as UTF-8 does not suffer from byte ordering issues in the first place. If your editor allows it, make it omit the BOM for UTF-8 output.

Comment: @DevSolar yes as was explained at length in comments under the original question although I have since deleted most of that comment thread.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some examples to make explicit some detail (implicit in the other answers), which may help clear up any remaining confusion.

Consider the following Unicode text `añ©ⱥ` which consists of:

- [U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A](https://codepoints.net/U+0061), encoded in UTF-8 as `61`
- [U+00F1 LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE](https://codepoints.net/U+00F1), encoded in UTF-8 as `C3 B1`
- [U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+00A9), encoded in UTF-8 as `C2 A9`
- [U+2C65 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH STROKE](https://codepoints.net/U+2C65), encoded in UTF-8 as `E2 B1 A5`

A byte is a number from 0 to 255 in decimal, or `00` to `FF` in hexadecimal. So when encoded with UTF-8, the above "four-character" string corresponds to, in the file, the 8 bytes `61 C3 B1 C2 A9 E2 B1 A5`.

### tex/pdftex WITHOUT inputenc

The engine sees the input as a stream of bytes (8 bytes in the above example). It considers each of them as as a character, and decides to typeset the corresponding character from either the [T1 (Cork) encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cork_encoding&oldid=780557442#Character_set) or OT1 encoding (the default) or whatever is set up. Examples:

[image: OT1]
Above, OT1 has no characters for those bytes so nothing gets typeset.
[image: T1]
I hope you can see what's happening: each of the 8 bytes is treated as a character and output: e.g. the byte `C3` is “Ã” in [T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cork_encoding&oldid=780557442#Character_set).

### tex/pdftex WITH inputenc

With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, TeX correctly sees every sequence of UTF-8 bytes as a Unicode character. For example, when TeX sees the byte sequence `C3 B1`, it understands that you mean the Unicode character U+00F1. (The way this is done is that bytes larger than 127 (`80` to `FF` in hexadecimal) are set up to be active characters that expect further input — this is possible because of a useful design of UTF-8. See [`texdoc utf8ienc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/utf8ienc.pdf) for details.)

TeX still needs to know what to do with that Unicode character. A big bunch of definitions (such as `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F1}{\~n}` saying what to do with the character U+00F1) are included in the TeX distribution (file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def` on TeX Live). So using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` will help *if* your characters have such definitions (again, see [`texdoc utf8ienc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/utf8ienc.pdf) for the full list), or if you're willing to define them yourself.

[image: inputenc]

### With a Unicode-aware engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX)

You don't need inputenc. The engine will expect UTF-8 (by default), and understand the input simply as Unicode characters, and for each of them it simply typesets that character from the currently selected font.

[image: xetex]

### What about BOM?

With UTF-8 the BOM (byte order mark) isn't needed (it was meant for non-byte-oriented encodings, like UTF-16 and UTF-32), and is strongly discouraged. Typical “good” editors won't include it. Just forget about it; you aren't likely to encounter it in practice.

But if somehow your file does end up including it, then it's just a sequence of bytes `EF BB BF` (the UTF-8 encoding of U+FEFF), and I think you have enough information above to work out what would happen if those bytes were present in the file at what place.

### What if my file contains only "normal" characters?

If you mean Latin-script characters without accents, then UTF-8 has the property that it coincides with ASCII on the range 0 to 127 (`00` to `7F`). So a file containing only those characters, encoded in UTF-8, is indistinguishable from one encoded in ASCII. Naturally, the output is identical too.

Answer (score 7):

The answer in 2020 is different from when you asked the question.  The LaTeX kernel has selected `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` by default since April 2018.

As of 2020, you only need (and should only use) `inputenc` if you need to compile files in another encoding on a non-UTF-8 engine.  Even there, it might be a good idea to use `selinput`, so that the file will still work if it gets converted to another encoding.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of TeX engines: ones that expect UTF-8 (e.g. LuaTeX and XeTeX), and ones that don't (e.g. pdftex).

If a TeX engine that expects UTF-8 is fed a UTF-8-encoded .tex file, the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` command can be omitted. In fact, a warning will be issued if it's not.

If a TeX engine doesn't expect UTF-8, and the TeX file contains non-ASCII characters, and the file doesn't contain a suitable `inputenc` command, strange output may result, as demonstrated by [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370280/21685).

Comment: A UTF-8 file starting with a BOM and processed with pdflatex will raise errors and compile wrongly. You need nothing else than the BOM to make it fail, so whether you load `inputenc` or not is actually irrelevant: this is true, but completely useless information.

Comment: This answer is entirely misleading. If the file is ascii then `inputenc` is not needed. If you are using luatex or xelatex then `inputenc` will generate a warning but otherwise do nothing. If you are using pdflatex or latex and the file uses any utf8 encoding other than the trivial ascii subset then `inputenc` is needed. the BOM is unrelated to inputenc it may (like any character before `\documentclass` give errors)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You say that the answer is entirely misleading and then you repeat my conclusion to the word... :)

Comment: No. Any normal reader who reads `A UTF-8 encoded .tex file does not require the \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} if it starts with a BOM or if only ASCII characters were encoded in it.` would read that as saying that you can use a BOM as an alternative to inputenc. You may as well say that you do not need inputenc if there is a `X` before `\documentclass`, it is exactly the same. the fact that it is a BOM is completely irrelevant

Comment: if pdftex only expected "pure ascii" then the output from my answer would not include non-ascii characters such as the accented A.

Comment: it's better after the edit but still gives bad advice. In the second paragraph `can be omitted, as it has no effect.` should say `should be omitted as otherwise it gives a warning message` in the third paragraph `its behavior is undefined`  is wrong, there is no behaviour that is undefined or system dependent here, some behaviours may give errors or be otherwise not useful but the behaviour is defined in all cases. It's not true that the file has to be ascii up to that point for example `\usepackage{ÉÉÉ}` should work, or you could have comments that were not ascii.

Comment: This is still wrong. UTF-8 engines will issue a warning if `inputenc` **is** loaded not if it isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When using TexShop on MacOS Catalina, inputenc is not the whole story. You also have to set UTF-8 in the TexShop preferences. Tab Source, Pulldown Encoding.

Comment: How is TexShop related to GNU Emacs (The editor used by the OP)?

Comment: It isn't, obviously. But the question isn't "Is there any reason to use inputenc when using GNU Emacs as an editor", it's "Is there any reason to use inputenc".

So, yes, you need inputenc but be aware that on some systems it is not the whole story.