# File names with spaces stopped working in \includepdf and \includegraphics in TeX Live 2019 if compiled with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, texlive, pdfpages, includegraphics, texlive-2019

Now the problem from [*File names with spaces stopped working in \includepdf and \includegraphics in TeX Live 2016 if compiled with LuaLaTeX*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327153) has arrived to XeLaTeX.

After upgrading my system (to NixOS 20.03) and TeX Live distribution (to TeX Live 2019), I can no longer use file names with spaces in `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf` (from `pdfpages`) using [`grffile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package **if I compile with XeLaTeX**.

Here is a minimal broken example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grffile}  % Extended file name support for graphics
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{a b.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `a b.pdf' not found on input line 6.

! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'a'.
<to be read again> 
               b
l.6 \includegraphics{a b.pdf}
```

Why does it not work anymore?

Note: it still works with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Exactly what did you install? I've just updated to Upstream TeXLive 2019 frozen this morning. I have no issues with your example under pdflatex or xelatex (granted I used a png instead).

Comment: I want to know whether you're using upstream TeXLive (directly from the developers) or you're getting it via your OS, in which case they should make sure to make the proper updates.

Comment: Don't use grffile anymore. File names with spaces should work without it. Beside this: show the complete log-file so that we can see the versions of your packages.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, could you please post this as an answer? Everything works, including LuaLaTeX, if i just remove `\usepackage{grffile}`.

Comment: Well normally grffile shouldn't harm (the current version does nothing). Do you have an older version in your search path? My version is 2019/11/11 v2.1 .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, indeed, i have `Version: 2017/06/30 v1.18` of `grffile`.  My TeX Live installation is managed by Nix package manager. Maybe i should submit an issue report.

Comment: And which latex version do you have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/NixOS.org)`.

Comment: not the binary, the latex version. There should be a line like `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5` in the log.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1`.